# Find and Replace a character in a string in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, string-search

I have a certain input string in this form: "[3] [4] at [5]"

From the following datatable, I need to replace the text on the datatable corresponding to the column index inside the bracket.

[image]

The output should be: "15A Circuit Breaker #348901836 at 19-Afalcon St. Capitol Subdivision"

Right now, I am using Regex.Replace() method but it searches for a particular pattern. My problem is the integers (corresponding the column index) enclosed inside the brackets is dynamic.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.Format should do it for you. Both the format string and the arguments can be easily implemented dynamically.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

All of the syntax, and a decent example of what you wish to do are on the linked page.

Comment: I tried String.Format just now. However, I have no control to the number of arguments (i.e. user can input: "[2]" ordered [3][4] on [0] to be delivered at [5]") String Format Requires: String.Format(pattern, arg1, arg2..)

Comment: In `String.Format`, the arguments are put in their corresponding indexes, not in the order they are put. In you example: "[2] ordered [3][4] on [0] to be delivered at [5]", `arg1` of the `String.Format` would replace `[0]`, it doesn't matter if it is at the beggining, the end, or even repeated. As for the values, you can create an array with the necesary strings and pass it as the second parameter.